# Azure AD B2C Custom policy for terms and condition with open id connect protocol

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using this example https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou to implement Terms and Condition custom policy for Azure AD B2C user which is working fine

I have another flow which integrates Azure AD Users as well which works on Open ID connect protocol I am try to implement same flow. But when implementing I get protocol error

Invalid technical profile with id "AADProvider-OpenIdConnect" only the protocol handler ""Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"" can have a ValidationTechnicalProfile.Invalid technical profile with id "AADProvider-OpenIdConnect" only the protocol handler ""Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"" can have a ValidationTechnicalProfile.

Below is my sample Technical profile

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>Contoso</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Login using Contoso</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AADContoso-OpenIdConnect">
      <DisplayName>Contoso Employee</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your Contoso account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ContosoAppSecret"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TOUConsentChoice" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Is there any work around for this

Comment: Could you please share your custom policy ? As the error message explained, only self asserted TP (user inputs) can have validation TP.

Comment: I have updated in the question